# Cumulative sum on preceding rows in the same column - R

Tags: r

data:

```
    test <- structure(list(fgu_clms = c(14621389.763697, 145818119.352026, 
21565415.2337476, 20120830.8221406, 12999772.0950838), loss_to_layer = c(0, 
125818119.352026, 1565415.23374765, 120830.822140567, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

    > test
   fgu_clms loss_to_layer
1  14621390           0.0
2 145818119   125818119.4
3  21565415     1565415.2
4  20120831      120830.8
5  12999772           0.0
```

I want to create a new column which tries to use a cumulative sum on the rows above it. It's easier if I show how the calculation on the new column works row by row:

row 1: first calculate the sum the value of rows above in the same column. As this is row 1 there are no rows above this value is 0, call this cumsum_1. It should then take the minimum of the value of row 1 in column "loss_to_layer" and the calculation "x2 - cumsum_1".

In row 2: calculate the cumsum by looking at the value above, i.e. min(x2-cumsum_1,loss_to_layer value). Call this cumsum_2. Then repeat as above, i.e. be subject to the minimum of the value on row 2 of the loss-to_layer column and x2 - cumsum_2.

And so on.

In excel, this would be done by using MIN(B2,x2 - SUM(C$1:C1)) and dragging this formula down.

The results with x2 = 127,000,000 should be:

```
   fgu_clms loss_to_layer   new_col
1  14621390           0.0         0
2 145818119   125818119.4 125818119
3  21565415     1565415.2   1181881
4  20120831      120830.8         0
5  12999772           0.0         0
```

As you can see the sum of the "new_col" always sums back up to "x2", in this case 127,000,000.

I have tried:

```
test <- test %>% mutate(new_col = pmin(loss_to_layer,127e6-cumsum(lag(new_col,1,default=0))))
```

But get an error as it cannot find the column new_col in the lag function

Comment: @akrun sorry what do you mean

Comment: @akrun Yes that's the problem - that was only my attempt, but I want the new_col to be created with values looking at rows above, but I'm not sure how I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test %>% 
  mutate(
    cumsum_1 = cumsum(lag(loss_to_layer, default = 0)),
    new_col = pmin(loss_to_layer, 127000000 - cumsum_1),
    new_col = ifelse(new_col < 0, 0, new_col)
  ) %>%
    select(-cumsum_1)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.